# Как ускорить код на питоне? Эффективная быстрая сортировка

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, циклы

У меня есть код, который не проходит по лимиту времени исполнения. Как можно улучшить и ускорить код?

---

Тимофей решил организовать соревнование по спортивному программированию, чтобы найти талантливых стажёров. Задачи подобраны, участники зарегистрированы, тесты написаны. Осталось придумать, как в конце соревнования будет определяться победитель.
Каждый участник имеет уникальный логин. Когда соревнование закончится, к нему будут привязаны два показателя: количество решённых задач Pi и размер штрафа Fi. Штраф начисляется за неудачные попытки и время, затраченное на задачу.
Тимофей решил сортировать таблицу результатов следующим образом: при сравнении двух участников выше будет идти тот, у которого решено больше задач. При равенстве числа решённых задач первым идёт участник с меньшим штрафом. Если же и штрафы совпадают, то первым будет тот, у которого логин идёт раньше в алфавитном (лексикографическом) порядке.
Тимофей заказал толстовки для победителей и накануне поехал за ними в магазин. В своё отсутствие он поручил вам реализовать алгоритм быстрой сортировки (англ. quick sort) для таблицы результатов. Так как Тимофей любит спортивное программирование и не любит зря расходовать оперативную память, то ваша реализация сортировки не может потреблять O(n) дополнительной памяти для промежуточных данных (такая модификация быстрой сортировки называется "in-place").

**Как работает in-place quick sort**
Как и в случае обычной быстрой сортировки, которая использует дополнительную память, необходимо выбрать опорный элемент (англ. pivot), а затем переупорядочить массив. Сделаем так, чтобы сначала шли элементы, не превосходящие опорного, а затем —– большие опорного.
Затем сортировка вызывается рекурсивно для двух полученных частей. Именно на этапе разделения элементов на группы в обычном алгоритме используется дополнительная память. Теперь разберёмся, как реализовать этот шаг in-place.
Пусть мы как-то выбрали опорный элемент. Заведём два указателя left и right, которые изначально будут указывать на левый и правый концы отрезка соответственно. Затем будем двигать левый указатель вправо до тех пор, пока он указывает на элемент, меньший опорного. Аналогично двигаем правый указатель влево, пока он стоит на элементе, превосходящем опорный. В итоге окажется, что что левее от left все элементы точно принадлежат первой группе, а правее от right — второй. Элементы, на которых стоят указатели, нарушают порядок. Поменяем их местами (в большинстве языков программирования используется функция swap()) и продвинем указатели на следующие элементы. Будем повторять это действие до тех пор, пока left и right не столкнутся.

---

**Формат ввода**

В первой строке задано число участников `n`, `1 ≤ n ≤ 100 000`.
В каждой из следующих n строк задана информация про одного из участников.
i-й участник описывается тремя параметрами:
уникальным логином (строкой из маленьких латинских букв длиной не более 20)
числом решённых задач Pi
штрафом Fi
Fi и Pi — целые числа, лежащие в диапазоне от 0 до 109.

---

**Формат вывода**

Для отсортированного списка участников выведите по порядку их логины по одному в строке.

---

***Пример 1:***

**Ввод:**

```
5
alla 4 100
gena 6 1000
gosha 2 90
rita 2 90
timofey 4 80
```

**Вывод:**

```
gena
timofey
alla
gosha
rita
```

---

***Пример 2:***

**Ввод:**

```
5
alla 0 0
gena 0 0
gosha 0 0
rita 0 0
timofey 0 0
```

**Вывод:**

```
alla
gena
gosha
rita
timofey
```

---

Python 3.7.3 | Ограничение времени: 2 секунды | Ограничение памяти: 64Mb

Мой код отрабатывает за: 2.084 секунды | 27.78Mb

---

Мой код:

```
class Participant:
    def __init__(self, name, tasks_solved, penalty):
        self.name = name
        self.tasks_solved = tasks_solved
        self.penalty = penalty

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.__gt__(other) or self == other

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.__lt__(other) or self == other

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if self.tasks_solved != other.tasks_solved:
            return self.tasks_solved < other.tasks_solved

        if self.penalty != other.penalty:
            return self.penalty > other.penalty

        return self.name > other.name

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.tasks_solved != other.tasks_solved:
            return self.tasks_solved > other.tasks_solved

        if self.penalty != other.penalty:
            return self.penalty < other.penalty

        return self.name < other.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


def quicksort(alist, start=None, end=None):
    if start is None is not end is None:
        raise AttributeError('PROVIDE BOTH ARGUMENTS OR NONE')

    if start is None and end is None:
        start = 0
        end = len(alist)

    if end - start > 1:
        p = partition(alist, start, end)
        quicksort(alist, start, p)
        quicksort(alist, p + 1, end)


def partition(alist, start, end):
    pivot = alist[start]
    i = start + 1
    j = end - 1

    while True:
        while i <= j and alist[i] <= pivot:
            i = i + 1
        while i <= j and alist[j] >= pivot:
            j = j - 1

        if i <= j:
            alist[i], alist[j] = alist[j], alist[i]
        else:
            alist[start], alist[j] = alist[j], alist[start]
            return j            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    reader = open('input.txt', 'r')
    length = int((reader.readline()))

    participants = list()

    for i in range(length):
        name, tasks, penalty = reader.readline().strip().split(' ')
        participants.append(Participant(name, int(tasks), int(penalty)))

    reader.close()

    quicksort(participants)

    print(*participants, sep='\n')
```

Comment: где-то тут уже был Тимофей с его "решённых задач Pi и размер штрафа Fi"...

Comment: я его видел, но вопрос удалили :(

Comment: внутри def quicksort        можно убрать первое условие и raise ?

Comment: да, можно убрать

Comment: 2.075s , 26.46Mb

Comment: а если здесь `if start is None and end is None:` попробовать наоборот: сначала проверять end?

Comment: 2.08s , 26.47Mb

Comment: пробовал сделать тупо через input - не сработало, чуть-чуть лучше стало, но не то

Comment: А как проверяющая система контролирует О-большое по памяти для интерпретируемого языка со сборщиком мусора?

Comment: если вы говорите о том, как он определяет время и т.п. - понятия не имею, на яндекс.контесте делаю

Comment: такое ощущение, что что-то не так в `def partition(alist, start, end):`

Comment: Вы уверены, что выбирать в качестве опорного первый элемент - это такая уж удачная идея?